# How can I multiply more than 3 vectors at once in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, multiplication

I'm looking for a vectorised way to multiply more than 3 vectors in NumPy.

As an example,

```
X = np.array([1,2,3])
Y = np.array([4,5,6])
Z = np.array([7,8,9])


Multiply([X,Y,Z])
```

would produce as an output

```
np.array([28, 80, 162])
```

The vectors I want to multiply need not to be defined separately as I did above. The could be, for example, the rows (or columns) of a matrix, and in that case I would like to multiply all the rows (or columns) of such a matrix.

Helps appreciated :)

Comment: Can you concatenate them using `np.stack` and then call `np.prod` along the new axis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` method of the ufunc:

```
>>> np.multiply.reduce((X, Y, Z))                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
array([ 28,  80, 162])
```

What's going on here is that the ufunc `np.multiply`, which looks and acts like function, is technically an instance of the class `numpy.ufunc`; all ufuncs have [four special methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#methods), one of them being `.reduce()`, which does what you're looking for in this case and produces a 1d result from multiple same-length 1d arrays.

The default axis is 0; if you want to work along the other axis, just specify that:

```
>>> np.multiply.reduce((X, Y, Z), axis=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                
array([  6, 120, 504])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy.prod`, which uses `multiply.reduce` under the hood.

---

```
>>> np.prod([X, Y, Z], 0)
array([ 28,  80, 162])

>>> np.prod([X, Y, Z], 1)
array([  6, 120, 504])
```

Answer (score 0):

Or very simply use the usual `*` notation:

```
In [180]: X * Y * Z
Out[180]: array([ 28,  80, 162])
```

---

In general, you can use as many arrays as you need:

```
In [181]: X * Y * Z * X * Y * Z
Out[181]: array([  784,  6400, 26244])
```

Comment: I was kind of assuming the question concerned a variadic arg, i.e. `multiply_arrays(*arrays)`, or `multiply_arrays(arrays)` (sequence arg).  If not, this would definitely be simpler